# how to test Xcode app on real iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

i want to test my app on my iPhone ... i created app id and i plug my device into mac 
i have these errors ...

1-Automatic signing failed
Xcode failed to provision this target. Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ and include the Update Signing report from the Report navigator.
2-No profiles for 'com.companyname.iosfed' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.companyname.iosfed'.
my iPhone is ios 11.2.2  and i use Xcode 9.2

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYaEA.png**strong text**

Comment: Quit XCode and retry it again.

Comment: the same error :(

Comment: Hmm okay go to developer.apple.com, sign in. Choose certificates & profiles on the left menu. Create a new certificate (iOS App Development). Choose the same appID you originally registered. Download it and double click it to install it. Now try signing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Change your bundle Identifier (Bundle ID).